# как с помощью регулярного выражения проверит, что слово (аббревиатура) с точками (например N.Y.T. или U.S.A) присутствует в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения

у меня есть массив слов  и текст. слова необходимо проверить на наличие в тексте и выставить true/false.
метод contains не помогает - так как он не видит различие между ours и hours,
я пробовал регулярку "\b("+word+")\b" - отлично, но не работает с  N.Y.T. или U.S.

тут нужно или переписать регулярное выражение, или как то разбить текст с абзацами и пробелами на отдельные слова.
и уже их проверить contains.
помогите с правильным алгоритмом.
Спасибо.

Comment: Дайте определение аббревиатуре

Comment: Вот для начала: `\b([A-Z]\.)+(?:\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/AxJKXM/1

Comment: Python? `r"(?<!\w)" + re.escape(word) + r"(?!\w)"`.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. в моем случае помогла простая модификация "\b(someString)(\b|\B)" Обязательно прочту книгу по регулярным))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
r"(?<!\w){}(?!\w)".format(re.escape(word))
```

Регулярное выражение найдёт `word`, сразу перед и после которого нет "словногоЭ символа: буквы, цифры и знака подчёркивания.

Граница слова - `\b` - находит разные позиции в строке в зависимости от контекста. Если `\b` находится перед "несловным" символом, например точкой, `\b\.`, тогда перед точкой должен стоять "словный" символ. Если граница слова стоит после точки, после точки должна быть буква, цифра или `_`.

Пара блоков предварительного просмотра `(?<!\w)` и `(?!\w)` однозначны независимо от контекста: блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!\w)` требует начала строки или символа, отличного от буквы, цифры или знака подчёркивания сразу перед точкой (`(?<!\w)\.`) и блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!\w)` требует конца строки или символа, отличного от буквы, цифры или знака подчёркивания сразу после точки (`\.(?!\w)`).